# Ceiling fan screws don’t match junction box

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have an older MinkaAire fan I’m trying to install. The instructions say “Use the two 8-32x3/4" screws”. The junction box says “Mount fan to posts with #10-24 screws”.
Is the fan just using an older spec?
The fan-supplied screws are too small for the box posts, of course.
Should I just get some 10-24s that fit the mounting bracket?

Also, the box has two pairs for posts. Which do I attach to?
[image]

Comment: do the box-suplied screws fit through the fan's support holes?

Comment: Looks like your two sets of posts have different spacings—probably to serve different devices.  I'm not seeing any obvious fasteners for the box itself—how is *it* supported?

Comment: If you look closely, there are two round uncovered holes. You can see metal behind them which to me looks like a bracket (with a saddle). One of the pairs of posts is hex-shaped. These are (not sure what they called) “extenders” that are screwed on to posts coming through the box’s back (with additional screws going into them on the “down” side). My guess is that those are the attachments to the bracket/saddle. 
Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple.

Use the 2 posts that fit the fan mounting bracket. If both fit, the post combination the will allow the mounting to be at the widest point should be chosen. This will make the bracket the most stable to the box and ceiling.
(The spacing is not critical, but a better choice.)

Use the #10 24 screws that fit the box.

Comment: We like simple!!